# missing brace in conditional statement doesn't produce an error

Tags: javascript

I am re-factoring some code and came across the following:

```
  if (window.init) init();  // check that init() function exists before using it
}
```

notice the missing opening brace `{` which would mean the statement should look something like this:

```
if (window.init) {
  init();
}
```

I would expect the original to error, causing some kind of break but nothing, works fine apparently. Should this code error? If not why not?

The only thing i can think of is that the overall function is closed by the extra `}` and then the `<br/>`
`if (window.init) init();` is just ignored for some reason.

as example:

```
function test() {
  if (window.init) init(); //ignored
}
```

---

**Note:** The `init()` function is not a built in javascript function.

Comment: That `}` obviously belongs to something else. Use an editor with bracket matching (Notepad++ is my preference) and see what comes up (I can place the cursor next to the brace and press Ctrl+B to jump to the matching one)

Comment: Single-line statements don't have to have braces, but I would definitely recommend them: `if (window.init) { init(); }`. It looks a little uglier but can save you running into problems.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - i knew the } belonged to something else as there was no opening brace, so it closed the above function as in my example. What i didn't know what was what Andy just said, the reason it didn't error is because single line statements don't need braces.

Comment: @Andy thanks for clearing it up, feel free to write it as an answer. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single-line statements don't have to have braces, but I would definitely recommend them. For example:

```
if (window.init) { init(); }
```

It looks a little uglier but can save you running into problems.

Something like [`JSHint`](http://www.jshint.com/) will pick up on these kinds of issues if you choose to use it to check your data.